# how to use sed command with several slashes in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to use SED command with a variable that contains several `/` and i got the following error :

```
sed: -e expression 1, char 16: unknown option to s
```

this is my code and this is inside a script:

```
thispath=$(readlink -f $0)
sudo sed -i '13s/^/'"$thispath"'/g' /etc/rc.local
```

and the variable contains for example: `/home/user/script.sh`
i do not know very well the use of sed can somebody help me

Comment: You can use a different delimiter in the s command e.g: `sed 's#ab#cd#g'`

Answer (score 2):

The *s* command is *sed* allows you to use any character to delimit the *regex* and *replacement* parts. "/" is often a poor choice given how often you come across it in UNIX paths:

Try:

```
sudo sed -i '13s:^:'"$thispath"':g' /etc/rc.local
```

It is dangerous to do this directly on rc.local. So make a copy first.

Comment: just be aware that it's just a band-aid and will fail when the text contains `:` or `&` or `\1` or some other char/string that sed interprets as something other than a literal char.

Comment: If you're going to suggest making a backup, you may as well add a suffix to the `-i` switch e.g. `-i.bak` so that one is created by the code in your answer.

Comment: @EdMorton I guess `awk -v str="$var" 'NR==13{printf "%s", str}1' file` could fix the delimiter problem, but it's a bit more complex and doesn't handle inplace editing without a recent gawk.

Comment: Yup, as often is the case it's a choice between brief or robust. To use sed for this see http://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001.